# How to do FILTER on a set of durations in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to apply FILTER to a set of durations in a Google Sheets table. While searching for a solution online, I came across the TEXT function. But I can't figure out how to use it correctly.

Can you help me out?

For example I want to count all cells which have a duration below 40 minutes:
[image]

I also would like to know how to do this with durations between let's say 30 and 50 minutes.

Comment: I've also tried to get it to work with DURATION and TIME. but no luck on figuring it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in range `A1:B5` you have real time value, use `COUNTIF`:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:B5;"<" & 1/24/60*40)
```

[image]

if there is text, then add `TIMEVALUE` and `ARRAYFORMULA`:

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(TIMEVALUE(A1:B5);"<" & 1/24/60*40))
```

Comment: suits my needs. thanks alot. I figured out the formula to count values in between two durations myself:
    =COUNTIFS(A1:A10;">" & 1/24/60*30;A1:A10;"<" & 1/24/60*50)

Answer (score 1):

Bewteen 30 and 50 mins using `timevalue`:

```
=filter(A:A,TIMEVALUE(A:A)>1/24/60*30,TIMEVALUE(A:A)<1/24/60*50)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: why does this only work when the values are all in one column?

Comment: I was just demonstrating how it works on a column. You can extend the range to more columns if you need.